# igraph python import error

Tags: python, igraph

I want to use the python wrapper from igraph. Compiling igraph and installing python-igraph works fine, but when I try to import igraph I get the following error (see image link below):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/igraph/_igraph.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: igraph_gomory_hu_tree
```

[Error message screenshot](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140724/3xekmdcg.png)

Comment: Maybe you are starting Python from the igraph package directory, right after installation. That directory contains a subdirectory named `igraph`, and Python is trying to import that.

Comment: @GaborCsardi If I create a new directory and try to import igraph I get exactly the same error message,

Comment: Then maybe the Python and C igraph versions do not match?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: The version number is in the name of the file you download.

Comment: I used igraph-0.7.0 and python-igraph==0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had some trouble with igraph and python, my solution:

1. delete your currently installed version of igraph and python-igraph
2. create a new virtualenv with `pyvenv-3.4 yourVenv`
3. activate the virtualenv `. yourVenv/bin/activate`
4. install python-igraph within the virtualenv `pip install python-igraph`

That one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'wraptext' import that comes with python. Then use .fill() to wrap the text over the next line. That might work.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you give me a short code example?

Answer (score 0):

It's because python doesn't find the igraph library. You can simply `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/` (or wherever the file libigraph.so is located on your system).

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Tried for more than a day with all kinds of resources online for installing `python-igraph` on mac. And I also wasn't able to `import graph` in .py file or .ipynb. Though it did allow me to `import igraph` in terminal when launching python. My solution is to make a virtual environment, `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph`, then switch python from version 3.8 (which never passes the `igraph.test.run_tests`, Failed = 2) to 3.5 (passed the test). Hope it helps.